Used car depreciation cliff--is it a fable or real?
I keep reading about this sudden drop in value on transferring a vehicle from new to used. I'd like to ask the validity of this, how do we know it to be true? Is this an actual phenomenon backed by publicly shared figures or something more like a myth, rule of thumb, or just simply case by case and anecdotal?
Just poring over this site we see statements like the following:

A new car loses about 30% of its value the second you drive it off the lot. source


Couple thousand when you drive off the lot and half that in 3-5 years source


This, along with the "Drive-off the lot depreciation"-factor is why my dad told me to always buy almost-new cars instead of brand-new. source


A brand-new car arguably loses a large percentage of its value the moment it leaves the dealer's lot. source


That's the same amount you would instantly lose on 2010 model after it leaves the dealership. source


BRAND new car loses thousands in price when it drives off the lot. source


A new car loses 15-20% of its value the second you drive it off the lot. source


Note that car (especially new one) is one of things that lose values very quickly - so you can't really go with "I'll buy it and see how it goes, and sell it if it is not working financially" - you'd easily lose 20-30% of the value the moment you buy it. source


Given that a car loses at the very least 10% (a very conservative estimate, usually much more) in the first few months of owning it source


But if you can show me some actual examples of people selling a year old car for virtually the same price as new, I'd be very impressed.. also very interested because that seems like a great deal for me. Might depend on the country, but it's certainly not the case in the US or Austria source


That sounds like a new-car price. If it is, you can kiss $4k-$5k of that price goodbye the moment you drive it off the lot. You'll pay the worst part of the depreciation on that vehicle. source

This answer gives the most context regarding justification for this, it basically boils down to risks from unknown history that apparently come with a steep hit accordingly:

Buying products (not just cars) new means you are getting a product straight from a trusted supply chain. Buying used, even nearly new, raises a whole bunch of questions about the item. Has it been abused in some way? does it have some hard to pin down problem? Has it been involved in some form of crime? are the manufacturers warranties/support packages fully transferable?
You can try to answer these questions of course, but there is both a cost to answering them and an uncertainty in the quality of the answers. So in normal circumstances, used products, even nearly new ones, will trade at a significant discount over new products. source

But I'm curious about how people know this hit translates to thousands of dollars, and even 30% of the buy price of a car or any other percentage. How have these figures become part of our common knowledge and how can we verify any of this remains true?

Just to be clear I don't have any reason to doubt this phenomenon exists, I'd just like to have this common knowledge undergirded by factual verifiable things and explore if there's any actual statistics that can be evaluated should anyone wish to deep dive on the subject. This is also useful to break the bad news for folks trying to sell a new used car for a little less than what they paid, which admittedly isn't impossible, but probably very unlikely.

You can easily compare used and new car prices to observe decline in value, but there are people/companies that have large volumes of pricing data (Edmunds, Kelley Blue Book, Cars.com) that they can use/let others use to perform such analysis.

Have you made any attempt to websearch the statistics? The exact amount demands on the vehicle's availability (used car prices shot up when the "easy to win" trade war made new cars unavailable), desirability, and a host of other factors, but yes. It's a real effect, partly because people assume that if you are selling a newish car there must be something wrong with it that you haven't told them.

I spent today just combing through the claims from this site, which confidently certifies for me the existence of this common knowledge I honestly already knew of. Assembling the hard facts and reputable sources will come next. I could plug and chug a few spot checked examples on KBB but I’m looking for hard connections to specific percentages, basically show me the receipts kind of deal.

This is not a discussion forum. What is the answer you're expecting that would be better than the sources you already have?

Something that would stand up to a questioning skeptic basically. If KBB or Edmunds has open data, or maybe even state DMVs, that would be a very good standard like a CSV of all car sales in the past 5 years or previous year. Something along those lines. I’m not trying to trigger debate but invite the assembling of a defense to back the assertion with verifiable things if possible. We can start with assembling secondary sources of articles which cite studies as a starting point.

@jxramos then you should ask at skeptics@SE. We're here to help people with their personal financial situation, not to prove or disprove random claims. https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Yah you may have a good point, is this a meta sort of question about finances than anything actionable itself. The subject is finance related but it may still not be a close enough fit to be fully on topic. Skeptics SE is pretty broad in general but I wouldn’t mind if an admin did a question move over to there.

I refreshed the help page for on topic, this one’s a weird fit the closest I could think would be under Spending Wisely. A lot of those source quotes I include actually have all these people using these rules of thumb to inform others about spending wisely essentially. If I figure out a way to independently calculate these percentage drops I would think that would be a tremendous asset to the community. I sketched a partial answer so far.

Also note that requests for pointers to off-site resources are generally considered out of scope

Good blog or redit topic, maybe. Bad fit for Stack Exchange.

Could definitely be a blog post. So this is hardly a random claim, it is a recurring claim as I demonstrated and it’s directly related to finances in the selling space and wasting money. People aren’t born knowing this depreciation rule of thumb, it’s out there and there is probably some degree of information asymmetry on this topic. Why can’t we simply shore the claim up with references. I don’t mind doing the heavy lifting, my style is to post a question early and allow the community chime in while I research on my spare time and converge on an answer or a dead end.

So turning the criticisms around for everyone should the question just be narrowed to something more specific, “Used car depreciation—why is it 10-20% driving off the lot”? Is there really no space for a question like that, do questions that are not constrained enough have no place on SE? I’m kind of more of the opinion there are no dumb questions ask away and let’s see what we can learn about a subject together.

An Empirical Calculation of Actual Sales Data
This aggregate statistic could be calculated independently if one had access to VIN level sales data as told by a Certificate of Title form where the transfer data is registered. That form has the date, the mileage, and the sale price listed. Using California as an example we can see a sample title here https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv-virtual-office/title-transfers/, the front has the Vehicle ID Number, YR Model, Make and mileage (the mileage now reads), the back has the fields PURCHASE DATE as well as PURCHASE PRICE OR IF GIFT, SO STATE. If each of those fields formed the columns of a table we could filter to those purchase dates separated by some threshold time interval for the same VIN. We’d have two price points at which the price delta could be calculated and expressed as a percent diff to the previous price. Collecting many matching percent diffs would allow us to estimate this depreciation cliff objectively for a good sample size, and could even group by make and model if the counts are sufficient.
So now I ask, do DMVs submit to FOIAs or anything like that. For California it would seem they do support this use case, to some extent, consider the following page

Requesting Records in Bulk
If you need to request more than 15 records at once, please contact the DMV Materials Management Section.
https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/customer-service/request-vehicle-or-driver-records/

I need to follow through to ask what scale they support precisely.
Price Based Analysis
So it appears KBB tracks pricing data rather than pure sale data according to this source:

How does Kelley Blue Book get its data and information
KBB employees a team of about 200 statisticians and researchers. Every day, the KBB employees review the prices of different vehicles and see what they are selling for at dealerships, auctions, and private sales.
https://www.motorbiscuit.com/where-does-kelly-blue-book-get-its-data-from/

This second source further backs this pricing based analysis

Kelley assesses a wide array of different values to both used and new vehicles. For used vehicles some of them include: Trade-in value, typical listing price, fair purchasing price (CPO), and private party.
Kelley determines Blue Book values by analyzing pricing information from real-world used car prices, as well as industry developments, economic conditions, and location.
https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/113015/are-kelley-blue-book-values-accurate-and-reliable.asp

That’s probably the next closest best thing obviously if states aren’t willing to export population wide figures to the public. The drawback I see with this approach is that one never gets exposed to the actual negotiated price just a bunch of asking prices.
Still there are price diffs to find through KBB even using those asking prices. I’ll run a brief sampling off KBB with a few models to share with others soon to demonstrate this.
Fair Price Value
The price criticism is addressed through KBB which has a great page on what they call the fair price value and they share some high level details for the inputs of their pricing values (italics mine)

Fair Purchase Price
The Fair Purchase Price reflects a vehicle’s actual selling price and is based on tens of thousands of recent real sales transactions from auto dealers across the United States. The Fair Purchase Price is not calculated or based on a proprietary formula; instead it is derived from actual new vehicle sales and extensive knowledge of the marketplace.

So KBB does have some component based on actual sales figures, if even just a subset of all sales in a state which are those which passed through a dealer. That’s very impressive to build those relationships with so many sellers to accomplish this. This probably isn’t transparent as open data would be but it’s still worth knowing about.
